# Как вызвать метод одного из базовых классов?

Tags: c++

Как вызвать метод абстрактного класса если есть только указатель на класс, о котором я знаю только то что один из его родителей это этот абстрактный класс ?

```
class A {
    virtual void Init()=0;
};

class B {
public:
    int i;
    B() : i(0) {};
};

class C : public A, B {
public:
    int i;
    C() : A(), B() {};
    void Init() {};
};

class D : public A {
public:
    int i;
    D() : A() {};
    void Init() {};
};

// представим что тут нельзя написать A вместо void
void func(void* ptr); 

int main()
{
 C obj1;
 D obj2;

 func((void*)&obj1);
 func((void*)&obj2);

 return 0;
}

void func(void* ptr) 
{
 // так конечно работает, 
 // но как то это не красиво, хотя бы по отношению к D 
 ((C*)ptr)->Init(); 
}
```

**upd:**
Спасибо всем за участие, ответ `((A*)ptr)->Init();` конечно очевиден, подвела как всегда невнимательность, моя проблема крылась в том что множественное наследование не сильно уж работает с builder'овским VCL'ом, то есть если C и D VCL классы, то `((A*)ptr)->Init();` работать не будет, суровая реальность((

Comment: И зачем только множественное наследование добавили в C++? бррр

Comment: Кстати, множественное наследование тут не при чем

Comment: Правильный вопрос, конечно же, почему нельзя выбрать A* в качестве типа для параметра func.

Comment: Это, конечно, было бы самое правильное решение

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В производных классах унаследованный виртуальный метод тоже надо объявлять виртуальным

```
class C : public A, B {
public:
    int i;
    C() : A(), B() {};
    virtual void Init() {}; // то же в классе D
};
```

Тогда можно через указатель на базовый класс вызывать эту виртуальную функцию из производного класса

```
void func(void* ptr) 
{
 ((A*)ptr)->Init(); //будет вызываться функция либо C::Init, либо D::Init, смотря что передано
}
```

Или лучше так

```
static_cast<A*> (ptr)->Init();
```

И еще замечание: в классе `A` сделайте метод `Init()` `public`

Comment: В производных классах не обязательно объявлять унаследованный вирт. метод виртуальным, но можно это делать для улучшения читаемости.

Comment: Да, действительно. Не знал. Спасибо за информацию.

Comment: > Или лучше так
> static_cast<A*> (ptr)->Init();

@mikillskegg, а чем же лучше ? Увеличением объема кода ? ;)

Comment: Не увеличением объема кода, а тем что уродливые конструкции привлекают внимание к потенциально уродливым решениям.

Answer (score 2):

Каст в `A*` надо делать при вызове функции.

```
int main() {
 C obj1;
 D obj2;

 func(static_cast<A*>(&obj1));
 func(static_cast<A*>(&obj2));
}

void func(void* ptr) {
 static_cast<A*>(ptr)->Init(); 
}
```

Если так не сделать, и порядок баз будет изменен (`class C : B, A`), то внутри `func` указатель будет указывать на `B` (первую базу) а не на `A`.